# how to send multiple get request to using multiple url using javascript/angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

my requiremtn is  i have multiple no of  url need to test  one by one by get method to get response.

example follwing urls

1-https:scgncp.com/12041/.
2-https:ibm.com/120024/.
.....
.......
.......
......
......
.....
......
100- no fo urls.

test using

```
$http(url).then(function(response)
{
//write  status of response
},function errorfunction(response){

//error status code should be display here

}
```

need to test 100 urls  using above method or other way is there please help me

Comment: What about a loop?

Comment: Please, if you want to motivate people to help you, take some time to write a correct question. Look at it now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build an Array of Promises and execute them all with: `Promise.all(arrayOfPromises)`

Answer (score 0):

You can find in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168316/angular-q-returning-promise-multiple-http-calls) how to use `$q` to send multiple async calls

Here the idea:

```
var urlList = ["url1","url2","url3"];

$q.all(urlList.map(function (url) {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url
            });
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop, to loop over all the `urls` and make a request for each one:

```
var urls = ["https:scgncp.com/12041/", "https:ibm.com/120024/"];

urls.forEach(function(url) {
  console.log("Sending a request to: " + url);
  $http(url).then(function(response) {
    //write  status of response
  }, function errorfunction(response) {
    //error status code should be display here
  });
});
```